# Joining tables on either of 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a synonym database which has two tables, "synonyms" and "synonyms_relations" like so...

```
synonyms
-------
id
word

synonyms_relations
------------------
id
word1_id
word2_id
```

I want to be able to get all words that are related to each other. The synonyms_relations table DOES NOT have records for matches in both directions, meaning if word1 is linked to word2, there wont be a record linking word2 to word1 - its assumed to work both directions.

This is the query I have to find all synonyms of the word "car". It works, but it seems way too complicated for my needs. Is there a better more efficient way to write this?

```
SELECT
  s.`word`
FROM
  `synonyms` as s
WHERE s.`id` IN (
  SELECT `word1_id` FROM `synonyms_relations` WHERE `word2_id` = (SELECT `id` FROM `synonyms` WHERE `word` = 'car')
    UNION
  SELECT `word2_id` FROM `synonyms_relations` WHERE `word1_id` = (SELECT `id` FROM `synonyms` WHERE `word` = 'car')
)
```

Comment: Wondering if you could invert and select from the relation where id in word

Comment: and, presumably, no word is listed as a synonym of itself!

Comment: Your idea of using a UNION is fine. It's just the way in which you've done it that's poor

Comment: I cannot resist mentioning that it would be more intuitive to call the tables `words` and `synonyms` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would seem to offer what you are looking for:

```
SELECT  s.`word`
  FROM  `synonyms` s
    LEFT JOIN `synonyms_relations` sr1 ON sr1.word1_id = s.id
    LEFT JOIN `synonyms` s1 ON s1.id = sr1.word2_id
    LEFT JOIN `synonyms_relations` sr2 ON sr2.word2_id = s.id
    LEFT JOIN `synonyms` s2 ON s2.id = sr2.word1_id
  WHERE (s1.`word` = 'car' OR s2.`word` = 'car')
```

Effectively, joining all words that have a matching `word2_id` (via `sr1` and `s1`) and all words that have a matching `word1_id` (via `sr2` and `s2`).

Comment: Joining the same table with different aliases, perfect. Thanks!